# Matlab VLFEAT -multiple matching

Tags: matlab, opencv, computer-vision, vlfeat

I am performing SIFT matching with VLFEAT in Matlab.

A single match is simple to display: I followed [the tutorial.](http://www.vlfeat.org/overview/sift.html)

**Update 1:** (extracting the problem from my needs)

Next, I consider 4 different views of the scene: I want to match the feature found in the first camera (bottom left) with the others.

Images are already undistorted.

[image]

I could match the third image: I managed to correct the coordinates with offsets for a proper display.
I set high threshold (fewer points) to have a more understandable image. 
My code is posted below, then there will be the question

Pointing out that (it does not affect the question or the answer, only the variable names in my code)

> Since my 4 cameras are in fact a stereo camera moving in the space,
>   the 4 cameras (and relative outputs) are:
>
> *Bottom left*: left camera named **a**. The features in this image
>   are `fa`, descriptors `da`... 
> *Bottom right*: left camera
>   named **a**. The features in this image are `fb`, descriptors
>   `db`... 
> *Top left*: left camera named **a** in the previous
>   instant. The features in this image are `fa_old`, descriptors
>   `da_old`... 
> *Top right*: right camera named **b** in the
>   previous instant. The features in this image are `fb_old`, descriptors
>   `db_old`...
>
> Movements are smaller so I expected that SIFT could retrieve the same points.

This code finds points and performs the "blue matching" and "red matching"

```
%classic instruction for searching feature
    [fa,da] = vl_sift((Ia_f),'NormThresh', thresh_N, 'EdgeThresh', thresh_E) ;
% with the same line I obtain
%fa are features in the current left image (da are descriptors)
%fb are features in the current right image (db... )
%fa_old are features in the previous left image
%fb_old are features in the previous right image

%code from tutorials (find the feature)
[matches, scores] = vl_ubcmatch(da,db,thresh_SIFT) ;
[drop, perm] = sort(scores, 'descend') ;
matches = matches(:, perm);

%my code

figure(1) ; %clf ;
axis equal;
%prepare the image
imshow(cat(1,(cat(2, Ia_v_old, Ib_v_old)),cat(2,Ia_v,Ib_v)));

%matching between the left frames (current and previous)
[matches_prev, scores_prev] = vl_ubcmatch(da,da_old,thresh_SIFT) ; 
[drop_prev, perm_prev] = sort(scores_prev, 'descend') ;
matches_prev = matches_prev(:, perm_prev) ;

%find index of descriptors in common, write them in order
I = intersect(matches(1,:), matches_prev(1,:),'stable');
MI_1 = arrayfun(@(x)find(matches(1,:)==x,1),I);
MI_2 = arrayfun(@(x)find(matches_prev(1,:)==x,1),I);
matches_M = matches(:,MI_1(:));
matches_prev_M = matches_prev(:,MI_2(:));

%features coordinates in the current images (bottom)
xa = fa(1,matches_M(1,:)) + offset_column ;
xb = fb(1,matches_M(2,:)) + size(Ia,2); %+offset_column-offset_column ;
ya = fa(2,matches_M(1,:)) + offset_row + size(Ia,1);
yb = fb(2,matches_M(2,:)) + offset_row + size(Ia,1);            

%matching "in space" (blue lines)
space_corr = line([xa ; xb], [ya ; yb]) ;
set(space_corr,'linewidth', 1, 'color', 'b') ;
%plotting features
fa(1,:) = fa(1,:) + offset_column ;
fa(2,:) = fa(2,:) + offset_row + size(Ia,1);
vl_plotframe(fa(:,matches_M(1,:))) ;
fb(1,:) = fb(1,:) + size(Ia,2) ;
fb(2,:) = fb(2,:) + offset_row + size(Ia,1);
vl_plotframe(fb(:,matches_M(2,:))) ;

%matching "in time" %corrx and coor y are corrected offsets
xa2 = fa_old(1,matches_prev_M(2,:)) + corrx;  %coordinate per display
ya2 = fa_old(2,matches_prev_M(2,:)) - size(Ia,1) + corry;

fa_old(1,:) = fa_old(1,:) + corrx;
fa_old(2,:) = fa_old(2,:) - size(Ia,1) + corry;
fb_old(1,:) = fb_old(1,:) + corrx ;
fb_old(2,:) = fb_old(2,:) - size(Ia,1) + corry;

%plot red lines
time_corr = line([xa ; xa2], [ya ; ya2]) ;
set(time_corr,'linewidth', 1, 'color', 'r') ;
%plot feature in top left image
vl_plotframe(fa_old(:,matches_prev_M(2,:))) ;
%plot feature in top right image
vl_plotframe(fb_old(:,matches_ex_M(2,:))) ;
```

All works. I thought to repeat few lines of code and find the proper `matches_ex_M` index array **in the proper order** and finally connect the feature in the last (top right) image (with any one of the other images)

```
% one of many tries (all wrong)
[matches_ex, scores_ex] = vl_ubcmatch(da_old,db_old,thresh_SIFT) ;
[drop_ex, perm_ex] = sort(scores_ex, 'descend') ;
matches_ex = matches_ex(:, perm_ex);
Ib = intersect(matches_prev_M(2,:), matches_ex(1,:),'stable');
MIb_2 = arrayfun(@(x)find(matches_ex(1,:)==x,1),Ib);
matches_ex_M = matches_ex(:,MIb_2(:));
```

The problem is that a new intersection will cause a new reorder, and all the matches will be wrong. 
But I have admitted I have no more ideas, after trying all possible combinations of matching index arrays. The problem is that I can't perform either intersection between 3 arrays simultaneously, nor changing their order. Featured are well displayed in all 4 images and I can perform single matches from any image to another in different scripts. In the top right images, there are the same features but with different order.

What I obtain (obviously wrong)
[image]

Synthesizing my problem:

> I thought I should change the order of the points in the top right
>   frame to have a good "yellow" matching, but I don't know how to make
>   it without changing the order in the top left (this will destroy the
>   "red" matching" and/or the "blue matching")

Any idea? Any different strategies?
Thank you all in advance.

**UPDATE 2**: After thinking to switch from MATLAB + VLFEAT to Python(2.7) + OpenCV (2.4.13) (**I'd prefer to have a solution in Matlab and VLFEAT**) I [found this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22895092/6564973).
Someone could do that in C++. But I'm unable to convert it nor in Matlab neither in Python. 
A pythonic solution could be accepted as well (added proper tags for that reason).

Comment: I can't understand what specifically is your problem. You get good matching between the features in time and between cameras in the lower frames, and you want to use this to match between the upper frames? Is this it?

Comment: @Naveh I have good matching between the lower frames. The upper frames were the "previous" lower frames (in previous iteration). I substantially would like to have the same point retrieved in all 4 frames (if it is possible with iterative structure). Storing previous values, with a reorder I managed to have correspondance in 3 frames... but reordering the points in the top left frame I lose correspondance previously found with the top right frame. I forced to make a intersection + reorder because points found in next iteration (lower frames) could not be the same

Comment: @Naveh I thought I should change the order of the points in the top right frame to have a good "yellow" matching, but I don't know how to make it without changing the order in the top left (this will destroy the "red" matching")

Comment: So is it a matching issue or an indexing issue? It looks like a matching issue from the image. If so, I don't see what the order of the points has to do with it.

Comment: @Naveh I think this is both. In order to have this line working properly `time_corr = line([xa ; xa2], [ya ; ya2]);` I have to reorder the feature vector. But matching is done with descritptor vector. I couldn't modify this order to have the right yellow matching.

Comment: The reordering _is_ the matching! If your matching method gives you bad reordering then there is an issue with the method (or with the descriptors).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132372/discussion-between-naveh-and-marcoresk).

Comment: @marcoresk have you tried writing your own matching function? Maybe L2 distance doesn't really suit your needs. Or for example focus on matching the top images only, regardless of the other images, then just append the solution to the rest of the code

Comment: @Mark No I haven't. I relied on VLFEAT library for matching and detector functions, it will take me too much time write my own function. And I think it won't be useful: for every 6 possible couple of images the single match works. So the problem is still how to do the right "intersection", find the common descriptors in all 4 image and reorder every array to have the correct x,y matching

Comment: Instead of matching it with `fa_old`, can you show what happens if you match the features with `fb`?

Comment: @ilke444 I will update an image as soon as possible, but it will be the same messy group of yellow lines

Comment: Please provide the photos and your complete code.